# Thorntail 2.6.0.Final WildFly Dependecy Error

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, microprofile, thorntail

We currently updated the version of Thorntail in our project from 2.5.0.Final to 2.6.0.Final.

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13.redhat-00006 in https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-group has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:390)
    ... 47 more
```

It seems that WildFly cannot find the dependency: `rg.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13.redhat-00006`.

Comment: If you use some kind of a Maven proxy, such as Nexus, then this is tracked in https://issues.redhat.com/browse/THORN-2522 -- which contains a suggested fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the Maven repository https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/ to the list of proxied repositories. For more info check this blogpost https://thorntail.io/posts/announcing-thorntail-2-6-0-final/#_red_hat_maven_repository_requirement